# Android show image on TextView click

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

This is probably really easy for most of you guys, but since I'm still a beginner I'm having problems figuring it out. Anyway, I want a picture to show when a textview is clicked. I know how to set up the onClickListener, but dont know how to make the picture show up as the result of the text being clicked. What method would I use for it? Its a fixed image that I have in my drawable folder. Thanks

Comment: do you want an image to be shown from your Android resources?

Comment: Yes. The image is located in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ImageView inside your layout where you want to show your image and you can set imageView's visibility attribute to invisible to make it invisible to the screen.

**example:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCompass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mwImage"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Inside the OnClick of your button you can then set the Imageview visility to visible;

```
yourImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I will try this out. It seems simple enough. Thanks. 
EDIT: Okay, so although that does work, I kind of wanted the image to pop up separately because using the visibility trick still takes up room in the xml layout and for what I'm trying to do i will end up with a lot of "invisible images" or blank spaces which will make it look ugly.

Answer (score 0):

After you inserted your image into drawables, set an ImageView in your .xml as:

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width=""
android:layout_height=""
android:id="@+id/image"
android:src="@drawable/imagelocation"
android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Then in your class Activity, do this:

```
public class Templates extends Activity {

Button btnimage;
ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
btnimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnimage);

btnimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Yes, it is possible to show up ImageView on dialog. Follow this:

```
Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(this);
settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null));
settingsDialog.show();
```

Then your .xml should look something like:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:src="YOUR IMAGE"/>
<Button 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Show Image" android:onClick="dismissListener"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I was just told this by another user. The only problem with this method is when the images are invisible, they still are taking up space in the xml layout. For my app, I'm going to have a lot of invisible images which will make the layout look ugly because of all the empty spaces. So, can you help me make the image pop up on the screen when the text is clicked rather than just changing the visibility?

Comment: Or if there is a way to set the size to something small enough so that the invisible images don't take up too much space and within the onclick method I could switch visibility on and enlarge the picture back to its original size?

Comment: Alright, that looks more like what I've been searching for. I will try it shortly and be back with the results. Thanks buddy.

Comment: glad to help. if anything, comment here.

Comment: So I'm a little confused. Where do I add the dialog part? to the beginning of the java class or within the onclicklistener? Also, for the '(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null)' part, is the R.layout.image_layout supposed to be exactly like that or am I supposed to change it to match my imageView id?

Comment: Dialog part is in your onCreate. Ya you can play around with Inflater according to your needs, but this is the method.

Comment: Okay, so I got that part all set. I just have one tiny question. How do I connect that dialog part to the onClickListener? Do I just include the settingsDialog.show(); in the body of the onCLickListener method?

Comment: Actually, no not really. I get all the scripts right but the app force closes when I try to run it on my phone. I even tried to implement the dialog in a separate app but it kept force closing. I'm not sure what went wrong, so I'm just searching online to try and learn more about dialogs so I can figure out what I'm probably doing wrong.
Is there a way to set the image size in the ImageView to something tiny and invisble then have it become visible and enlarge it with the onClickListener? I think that would be an easier solution if the size conversions exist.